# Problems using PHP / fgetcsv when saving CSV data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Actually Iam reading a CSV file, I try using `fgetcsv` and opening as a socket with `fopen` + `fread`. The problem is when it save data to MySQL all data is shown but with jumps on the lines and spaces.

I also made a MySQLi class to talk with the DB

```
            $c = 0;
            $arreglo = Array();
            if (($file = fopen("/pth/to/file/DataParaCortesProgramados.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
                while (!feof($file)) {
                    $archivo = fread($file, 100000000);
                    $linea = explode("\n", $archivo);
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($linea as $campo) {
                        $camp = explode(",", $campo, 6);
                        if ($i > 2) {
                            $arreglo[$c]["UN"] = $camp[0];
                            $arreglo[$c]["ncliente"] = $camp[1];
                            $arreglo[$c]["cliente"] = $camp[2];
                            $arreglo[$c]["suscrip"] = $camp[3];
                            $arreglo[$c]["tiposervicio"] = $camp[4];
                            $arreglo[$c]["datoservicio"] = $camp[5];
                            $c++;
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach ($arreglo as $row){
                $ObjDBLink->INSERT("INSERT INTO `SuscripBI_copy` (`UN`,
                                                `ncliente`,
                                                `cliente`,
                                                `suscrip`,
                                                `tiposervicio`,
                                                `datoservicio`) VALUES 
                                                ('" . $row["UN"] . "', 
                                                 '" . $row["ncliente"] . "',  
                                                 '" . $row["cliente"]. "',
                                                 '" . $row["suscrip"]. "',
                                                 '" . $row["tiposervicio"] . "',
                                                 '" . $row["datoservicio"]. "')");
            }
```

==========================THIS IS WITH FGETCSV===========================

```
        if (($file = fopen("/path/to/file/" . trim($rowf), "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (!feof($file)) {
                $reg = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",");
                if ($rowc > 2) {
                    $clientes[$i]["UN"]=$reg[0];
                    $clientes[$i]["ncliente"]=$reg[1];
                    $clientes[$i]["cliente"]=$reg[2];
                    $clientes[$i]["suscrip"]=$reg[3];
                    $clientes[$i]["tiposervicio"]=$reg[4];
                    $clientes[$i]["datoservicio"]=$reg[5];
        //            var_dump($clientes);
                }
                $i++;
                $rowc++;
            }
        }

        foreach ($clientes as $cliente){
        //    var_dump($cliente);
            $ObjDBLink->INSERT("INSERT INTO `SuscripBI` (`UN`,
                                            `ncliente`,
                                            `cliente`,
                                            `suscrip`,
                                            `tiposervicio`,
                                            `datoservicio`) VALUES 
                                            ('" . trim($cliente["UN"]," \t\n\r\0\x0B") . "', 
                                             '" . trim($cliente["ncliente"]," \t\n\r\0\x0B") . "',  
                                             '" . trim($cliente["cliente"]," \t\n\r\0\x0B") . "',
                                             '" . trim($cliente["suscrip"]," \t\n\r\0\x0B") . "',
                                             '" . trim($cliente["tiposervicio"]," \t\n\r\0\x0B") . "',
                                             '" . trim($cliente["datoservicio"]," \t\n\r\0\x0B") . "')");
        }
```

This works, the data is saved on to the DB but it is saved with spaces or jumped lines
suvch as this:

> |  E m p l e a d o s  |  1 1 3 7      |

but need this:

> |  Empleados  |  1137      |

I have tried `trim($row["UN"], " \t\n\r\0\x0B")`, or use `str_replace` before saving, but it always saves the same - incorrect - way.

============SOLVED==============

The problem was the encoding of CSV file, was UTF-16LE and PHP READ UTF-8, to solve this i change with a shell command from UTF-16LE to UTF-8.

```
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 $file  > $file2
```

Comment: Can you show what that line of the CSV looks like?

Comment: please make use of prepared statements while inserting and updating data

Comment: If it's a CSV file why not use [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) instead of trying to roll your own?

Comment: Please go back to using `fgetcsv`, what you are currently doing is not the proper way to read CSV data, and will easily fail in many cases. The issue itself is probably with the character encoding the CSV data was saved in, so go figure out which one that was first of all.

Comment: Hi all and thx for your answer, i use fgetcsv and it's same result

Comment: You haven't shown your data, but can you also show what you tried with `str_replace`? Trim only trims the right and/or left, but not the middle, and the string that you show for replacing does not have the space character listed.

Comment: The PHP csv reading functions are not well made and this sort of problem has come up repeatedly for me. It's always been easier to create a custom function/class to process the *file* as you need, be it a CSV file or any other type,